# Can't connect via "vagrant ssh" to vagrant box created with "vagrant package"

Tags: vagrant, qemu, libvirt

A vagrant box which was created using "vagrant package" cannot be connected to using "vagrant ssh".

Note - I am using libvirt and QEMU, not Virtualbox.

I took a working vagrant instance and created a vagrant box using
`vagrant package --output abc.box`
`vagrant box add abc.box --name abc`

I then created an empty directory and generated the Vagrantfile using
`vagrant init`

I edited the Vagrantfile and set config.vm.box = "abc"
I then tried a "vagrant up", and it hangs on the SSH connection

I ran a "vagrant -ssh-config" which returns settings. I was able to use the IP and key listed there to connect to the instance.

Can anybody tell me what the correct process is for getting this kind of instance to start properly? Is it by design that the insecure access isn't preserved in the packaged box? Should I just be installing my own SSH keys and logging in using "ssh" instead of "vagrant ssh"?

I expected the "vagrant up" to complete, but it never returned the prompt. Attempts to connect to it using "vagrant ssh" from another terminal didn't work.

I turned on debugging and saw the log entries listed below.

````
DEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log START ==
DEBUG ssh: D, [2019-09-03T18:00:51.803268 #4837] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[1ae7be8]: establishing connection to 192.168.121.230:22
D, [2019-09-03T18:00:51.804016 #4837] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[1ae7be8]: connection established
I, [2019-09-03T18:00:51.804202 #4837]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[1ae6e64]: negotiating protocol version
D, [2019-09-03T18:00:51.804260 #4837] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[1ae6e64]: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_4.2.0 x86_64-linux'
D, [2019-09-03T18:00:51.814838 #4837] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[1ae6e64]: remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3'
I, [2019-09-03T18:00:51.815157 #4837]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[1adcbe4]: sending KEXINIT
D, [2019-09-03T18:00:51.815403 #4837] DEBUG -- socket[1ae792c]: queueing packet nr 0 type 20 len 1156
D, [2019-09-03T18:00:51.815504 #4837] DEBUG -- socket[1ae792c]: sent 1160 bytes

DEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log END ==
 INFO retryable: Retryable exception raised: #<Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - recvfrom(2)>
 INFO ssh: Attempting to connect to SSH...
 INFO ssh:   - Host: 192.168.XXX.XXX
 INFO ssh:   - Port: 22
 INFO ssh:   - Username: vagrant
 INFO ssh:   - Password? false
 INFO ssh:   - Key Path: ["/home/XXXXX/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"]
DEBUG ssh:   - connect_opts: {:auth_methods=>["none", "hostbased", "publickey"], :config=>false, :forward_agent=>false, :send_env=>false, :keys_only=>true, :verify_host_key=>false, :password=>nil, :port=>22, :timeout=>15, :user_known_hosts_file=>[], :verbose=>:debug, :encryption=>["aes128-cbc", "3des-cbc", "blowfish-cbc", "cast128-cbc", "aes192-cbc", "aes256-cbc", "rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se", "idea-cbc", "arcfour128", "arcfour256", "arcfour", "aes128-ctr", "aes192-ctr", "aes256-ctr", "cast128-ctr", "blowfish-ctr", "3des-ctr", "none"], :logger=>#<Logger:0x00000000034d08c0 @level=0, @progname=nil, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00000000034d0848 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x00000000034d07f8 @shift_period_suffix=nil, @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<StringIO:0x00000000034d0938>, @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x00000000034d07a8>>>, :keys=>["/home/XXXXXX/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"]}```
````

Comment: When you first provision your Vagrant box, Vagrant will authenticate using a 'insecure' public/private key pair. Vagrant boxes typically have this 'insecure' listed in /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys. When a Vagrant box boots for the first time, this insecure key is replaced with a new key. The default insecure key is stored at https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/tree/master/keys. You should probably install this key in your box before repackaging.